# Chrome is not started with selenium and behat

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, behat

Please help. I use windows to run my tests. I run selenium with chrome driver:

```
 java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

My behat_dev.yml :

```
default:
suites:
    default:
        mink_session: selenium2
        javascript_session: selenium2
        extensions:
            Behat\MinkExtension:
                base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
                default_session   : selenium2
                javascript_session: selenium2
                browser_name      : chrome
                goutte: ~
                selenium2         :
                    wd_host     : http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
                    browser: chrome
                    capabilities: { "browserName": "chrome", "browser": "chrome", "version":  "", 'chrome': {'switches':['--no-sandbox']} }
                sessions:
                    default:
                        selenium2: ~
```

My scenario :

```
Feature: Home page
    I am on a home page
@javascript
Scenario: Searching for a page with autocompletion
  Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
  When I fill in "search" with "Behavior Driv"
  And I wait for the suggestion box to appear
  Then I should see "Behavior-driven development"
```

The selenium is starting whitout problems, but when I try to run the tests nothing happen. The browser is not open. Please help me !!!!!! Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: what version of Behat do you have? 3?  Any errors in terminal or in selenium logs?

Comment: Yes, it the version 3. ... Logs from selenium : `16:51:10.354 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown'
16:51:10.355 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-06-28 16:51:10.380:INFO::main: Logging initialized @286ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog


`

Comment: Have you started Chrome in the background first? I had some issues with Chrome starting so I started it manually before running tests. Also check what the command `chrome-driver` says when run on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set `wd_host` for local run unless you are using a different port.

It should work with some simple config like:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org'
      selenium2:
        browser: chrome
```

Make sure you keep the indentation in yml, `suites` is under first `default`, not at the same level.

For extra verbosity use a `-vvv` at the end.