# Behat + Mink extension + Selenium foreach problems

Tags: php, symfony, selenium, behat, mink

I followed instruction from this doc http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html and everything seem good but everytime I try to test a scenario with Javascript I get a weird error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in vendor/behat/mink-selenium2-driver/src/Selenium2Driver.php line 444

My Behat.yml look like this

```
default:
    gherkin:
        cache: var/cache/test/behat/behat_gherkin_cache
    testers:
        rerun_cache: var/cache/test/behat/behat_rerun_cache
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\WebApiExtension:
            base_url: 'http://nginx:8001'
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: 'http://localhost:8000'
            selenium2: ~
            sessions:
                default:
                    symfony2: ~
    suites:
        default:
            paths: [ '%paths.base%/features/app' ]
            contexts:
                - FeatureAppContext
                - Knp\FriendlyContexts\Context\TableContext
```

And my scenario is

```
@javascript
Scenario: domain name reserve
  Given I am on "/login"
  When I fill in the following:
    | username | user_default |
    | password | test |
  Then I press "Connexion"
  Then I should be on "/"
```

But it fail at the first rules with the error mentioned above.

The Selenium2 jar is running too.

I really don't know why I get this error

Here is the problematic method from `SeleniumDriver.php`

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCookie($name)
{
    $cookies = $this->wdSession->getAllCookies();
    foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
        if ($cookie['name'] === $name) {
            return urldecode($cookie['value']);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have some ideas ?

Comment: What version of Behat do you have? See if you can get a more detailed exception, for version 2.5 add a `-v`,  for version 3+ add a `-vvv` to your execution command line.

Comment: I'm using behat 3.3-dev, the verbose option don't return more details than without...

Comment: And what driver/browser?

Comment: MinkSelenium2Driver version 1.3.1, I don't know which browser. I'm working on Ubuntu 16

Comment: In order to use javascript you need to use a driver that supports javascript and a browser. For example Selenium2 with Chrome and you need to start the selenium server with this browser, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468600/how-to-run-tests-in-behat-on-firefox-48-0-using-selenium-stand-alone-server

Comment: Yes i tried but when i execute java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar I get the same output as before...

Comment: You also need to set the browser under Mink, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804069/chrome-is-not-started-with-selenium-and-behat

Comment: Just as a point to consider - I would immediately add a `var_dump` of the `getAllCookies()` result to check what I am getting wrong. Most likely it's null or empty, because there's something wrong with the session object. And that is a clue to what's wrong.

Comment: The `getAllCookies()` method return null all the time